# How to return the table name used out of a delete statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I delete a user from my database, the database engine also cascade delete in other tables.

```
DELETE FROM Users WHERE Id = 'A022408A-745B-464C-93C4-30B45C55D1E3'
```

> (11 row(s) affected)
>       (224 row(s) affected)
>       (1 row(s) affected)
>       (1 row(s) affected)
>       (1 row(s) affected)
>       (32 row(s) affected)
>       (1 row(s) affected)
>       (56 row(s) affected)
>       (50 row(s) affected)
>       (6 row(s) affected)
>       (0 row(s) affected)
>       (1 row(s) affected)
>       (1 row(s) affected)

Is there a way to display the table name for each result, eg:

> (56 row(s) affected) in table Appointments

Comment: get the fk definitions from information_schema and filter out the ones that don't have a cascaded delete.

Comment: Think you need to set up triggers, extended events or similar to trace, if you want to match number of deleted rows to a table.

Comment: You could use `SET STATISTICS IO` in order to see tables names. But in this case, if there are triggers then `SET STATISTICS IO ON` will return, also, information (logical & physical reads, etc.) about tables accessed within/by triggers.

Comment: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS rc
WHERE rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PK_Users'
ORDER BY rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a long way round to solve this, but how about putting a trigger on all the tables that `PRINT`s out the table name whenever a row is deleted?

Not quite the same as what you're after, but it'd give essentially the same info. You could even have it return some other possibly useful into, such as the primary keys of the rows being deleted...